# nest js: npm run start fails in a new project

Tags: typescript, nest

Hello i've recently started nestjs and i've created a new project using the **nest new** command, when i want to start the project with npm run start:dev i get the error below in my console does anyone know the solution of this problem and thanks.

**node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16532:11** - *error TS2430*: Interface 'WebGL2RenderingContext' incorrectly extends interface 'WebGL2RenderingContextBase'.

Types of property 'clearBufferfv' are incompatible.

Type '(buffer: number, drawbuffer: number, values: ArrayLike | Float32Array, srcOffset?: number) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (buffer: number, drawbuffer: number, values: Float32List, srcOffset?: number): void; (buffer: number, drawbuffer: number, values: Iterable, srcOffset?: number): void; }'.

Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
        Type 'Iterable' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike | Float32Array'.
          Type 'Iterable' is missing the following properties from type 'Float32Array': BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, buffer, byteLength, byteOffset, and 25 more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue with the typescript compiler, which means that you probably have an outdated version of nest or typescript that your system is using. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33672

I've run through the setup and had no errors, and I get the following versions of the tools:

```sh
$ nest --version
7.1.4

$ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --version
Version 3.8.3
```

If you need to update nest, you can use the following command: `npm update -g @nestjs/cli`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have the same version of nest and tsc as you but i still have the same error it's very weird.

Comment: it was resolved i've deleted the webgl2 package and now it is working fine thank you.